# Making an interactive choropleth map with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, graphael

I am having trouble with a mapping project I just started.

I wanted to make an interactive map using RaphaelJS. I imported the SVG my map is based on from QGIS after converting it from a shapefile. And using some code from this example on Ready Set Raphael (http://jsfiddle.net/allankiezel/FJrNN/) I tried to make the provinces come to the front when the mouse hovers over them using the mouseover() method in the RaphaelJS library.

The full code is on JSfiddle because it would be too long to fit in here: http://jsfiddle.net/siyafrica/nCL25/

```
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '612', '792');

var SouthAfrica = rsr.set();
SouthAfrica.attr({'id': 'South-Africa','name': 'SouthAfrica'});

var easterncape = rsr.set(); ...

var len = rsrGroups.length;
    for(i = 0, i <= len, i++) {
       var el = rsrGroups[i];
el.mouseover(function() {
    this.animate({
            scale: '1.05'
        }, 200);
});
    };
```

I'm running this on a Macbook Pro using OS X.

I hope someone can help. I think the fix is simple but I've been racking my brain trying to find it.

Comment: I think there's some problem with the SVG you are using, maybe from the conversion even though it looks ok. Try just getting one simple object you have converted to use, then try more complex ones.

Comment: I played around with another SVG, deleted some whitespace and re-arranged the tags. This time I was able to animate one of the paths. What I want to do is animate all the paths so that if you mouseover them or click them they all will be affected.